# Why this won't get faster even if I solved n + 1 issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the gem called "bullet" in order to avoid N + 1 issue.

My previous code was

```
@communities = Community.scoped.page(params[:page]).order("created_at DESC")
```

Then I was getting this errors

```
N+1 Query detected
  Community => [:platform]
  Add to your finder: :include => [:platform]

N+1 Query detected
  Community => [:genre]
  Add to your finder: :include => [:genre]

N+1 Query detected
  Community => [:tags]
  Add to your finder: :include => [:tags]
```

Then it was taking about 650ms to show a page with over 70 sql.
So I changed it to this

```
@communities = Community.scoped.page(params[:page]).per(10).order("created_at DESC").includes(:platform, :genre, :tags)
```

Now, the alert of bullet is gone but it's taking 750ms and there are still over 70 sql.

Why is that?

This is the result of how long it's taking to show a page(w/ rack-mini-profiler)

[image]

For example, it's taking around 30ms for each `communities/_community`
It's probably because of `count`

Each `communities/_community` calls these 2 helpers. Could it be the reason of the large number of sql here?

```
def topic_button(community)
    last_post = community.community_topics.order('last_active_at DESC').first
    if last_post && last_post.last_active_at.today?
        link_to sanitize( "Topics ("+ community.community_topics.count.to_s+")" , community_community_topics_path(community)
    end
end


def uploader_button(community)
    last_post = community.community_uploaders.order('last_active_at DESC').first
    if last_post && last_post.last_active_at.today?
        link_to sanitize("Chat ("+ community.community_uploaders.count.to_s+")" , community_community_uploaders_path(community)
    end
end
```

**UPDATE**

**models/community.rb**

```
paginates_per 10
```

**controllers/communities_controller.rb**

```
@communities = Community.scoped.page(params[:page]).order("created_at DESC")
```

**/views/communities/index.html.erb**

```
<span class='community'>
    <% @communities.each do |community| %>  
        <%= render 'communities/community', :community => community %>
    <% end %>
</span>
```

**/views/communities/_community.html.erb**

```
<div class="Box">
    <div class="List">
        <p class="name"><span><%= community.title %></span></p>
        <%= community.community_name %>
        <p class="img">
        <% if community.community_icon? %>
            <%= link_to image_tag(community.community_icon.url(:medium), :alt => community.title, :style => "width: 250px; height: 250px", :class => 'img-polaroid' ), community_path(community.community_name) %>
        <% end %>
        </p>
        <div class="link">
        <%= platform_search(community.platform.name, community.platform_id) %>
        <%= genre_search(community.genre.name, community.genre_id) %>
        </div>
        <div class="intro">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Member</th>
                    <td class="border"><%= link_to community.cached_votes_up.to_s , bookmarker_community_path(community.community_name) %></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Publisher</th>
                    <td class="border"><%= link_to community.publisher, communities_path(:publisher => community.publisher) if !community.blank? %></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="body">Body</th>
                    <td class="border"><%= community.body.slice(0,55) if !community.blank? %></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="tag">Tags</th>
                    <td class="border">
                    <% community.tags.each do |tag| %>
                    <span><%= link_to tag.name, {:controller=>'communities', :action=>'index', :tag=>tag.name} %></span>
                    <% end %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>              
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <%= topic_button(community) %>
            <%= uploader_button(community) %>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <%= chat_button(community) %>
            <%= link_to sanitize('Codes ( ' + community.codes_count.to_s + ' )', community_codes_path(community), :class => 'btn' %>
        </div>
        <div class="follow">
            <span class="bookmark_community" community-id="<%= community.id %>">
            <%= render :partial => "communities/bookmark", :locals => {:community => community} %>
            </span>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

**application_helper.rb**

```
def topic_button(community)
    last_post = community.community_topics.order('last_active_at DESC').first
    if last_post && last_post.last_active_at.today?
        link_to sanitize("Forum ("+ community.community_topics.count.to_s+")" , community_community_topics_path(community), :class => 'red_button'
    else
        link_to sanitize( "Forum ("+ community.community_topics.count.to_s+")" , community_community_topics_path(community), :class => 'button'
    end
end

def uploader_button(community)
    last_post = community.community_uploaders.order('last_active_at DESC').first
    if last_post && last_post.last_active_at.today?
        link_to sanitize("Uploader ("+ community.community_uploaders.count.to_s+")" , community_community_uploaders_path(community), :class => 'red_button'
    else
        link_to sanitize("Uploader ("+ community.community_uploaders.count.to_s+")" , community_community_uploaders_path(community), :class => 'button'
    end
end

def chat_button(community)
    if !community.comment_threads.last.nil? && community.comment_threads.last.created_at.to_date == Date.current.to_date
        link_to sanitize('Chat', chat_community_path(community), :class => 'red_button'
    else
        link_to sanitize('Chat', chat_community_path(community), :class => 'button'
    end
end
```

**/views/communities/_bookmark.html.erb**

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <% if current_user.voted_up_on? community %>
        <%= link_to(bookmark_community_path(community), :remote => true, :class => 'button') do %>
            <i class="icon-remove"></i>
            Un-Bookmark
        <% end %>
    <% else %>
        <%= link_to(bookmark_community_path(community) ,:remote => true, :class => 'blue_button') do %>
            <i class="icon-bookmark"></i>
            Bookmark
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to(bookmark_community_path(community) , :class => 'blue_button') do %>
        <i class="icon-bookmark"></i>
        Bookmark
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Is it because I use count twice for each community?

Comment: Show your `_community` partial -- that's where it seems to be taking the lion's share of time (it takes 100ms+ to render sometimes).

Comment: @bdares Thanks. As a test, I deleted a part of those helpers from `_community` partial, and I could make sure that there are less sql queries. But it still takes time. It seems the duration of loading time is depending on something. It changes every time I load a page. It's always somewhere between 400ms - 700ms so that I feel all the same. If I want to make it faster than this, all I need to do is  page cache? but I cannot use it because it's twitter-like application:(

Comment: why are there two virtually identical questions on this topic?

Comment: sorry about that. I just want to know what would be bottle neck in this case

Comment: seriously.. show us the code.  If you just show us what you think is the problem, comment it out, and claim that it doesn't improve the time (obviously because code you're *not* showing us is taking time), what are we supposed to do?

Comment: @bdares I'm so sorry. I didn't mean that. I updated my answer and pasted all the codes that I could think of its related. Does this help?

Comment: I want to know what's making it so slow:(

Comment: You have other stuff that could be taking a while, like `platform_search()` and `genre_search()`.  Looks like you'll have to spend some time profiling this.

Comment: It's for search form.  Basically it's just listing up all theplatforms and genres as select choice. Does it make slow that much?

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to please go through you development log. You will definitely find how much time is taken by which process or partial. First clear your development log. And then refresh your page/action.

Another suggestion is use a class variable for methods like current_user,user_signed_in? . These are executed so many times.

```
@current_user = current_user
```

And then no need to use current_user anywhere. Just replace it to @current_user. In your development.log you will find the difference.

Similarly, for more speed you can use caching.

Comment: Thanks! I use current_user in all pages. So should I have your code in application_controller?

Answer (score 1):

For better performance select the required fields/columns from the tables.

It will save the system memory used for each request, and also save the time to fetch them from the database.

Use "select" method if you are using rails3 or you can use "select" option in the find method for rails2.

**You should not select specific fields if you using memory object caching system.**